# mousewheel scrolling over div

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I want to scroll down the content in a special div by using the mousewheel.

for Example

```
<tr>
    **<td>sendKeys</td> | 
    <td>css=myElement</td> |
    <td>mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);</td>
</tr>**
```

I need the mousewheel to scroll down while hovering the div, like modifying the scale in google maps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**UPDATED:**

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>window.document.getElementById('DIV-ID').scrollTop +=20</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Hope help!

Comment: thanks for your reply, but honestly im not sure how to translate your hint to a correct command in selenium ide?

Comment: @user3976239 Sorry, I didn't notice about selenium IDE. I've just updated my answser. hope help!